# Wrap plain text in paragraph Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an h2 and some text:

```
<h2>Test</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor hener ait
```

I need need to wrap the text "lorem ipsum dolor hener ait" in a `<p>` element. Hoping to get this result:

```
<h2>Test</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor hener ait</p>
```

Currently, I have this:

```
$('h2').each(function() {
     $(this).next().wrapAll('p');
});
```

But it does not work. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show more of the HTML please? Particularly, what comes after the text that needs to be wrapped?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all text nodes of the parent and wrap them with a p element. I don't know if this solution will work for your html structure though.

`contents()` will return all nodes including text nodes. The `filter()` I use makes sure only textnodes that contain characters get wrapped. White space for code alignment are textnodes as well.

```js
$('h2').each(function() {
  var textnodes = $(this).parent().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue.trim() !== '';
  }).wrapAll('<p>');
});
```

```css
p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor hener ait
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without jQuery.

Text are [HTML nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp), so you can access them using [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

```
for (let h2 of document.querySelectorAll("h2")) {
    let text = h2.nextSibling;
    let p = document.createElement("p");
    h2.parentNode.insertBefore(p, text);
    p.appendChild(text);
}
```

If it doesn't work as expected, the problem is that `h2.nextSibling` is not returning the text node, but another "invisible" text node you may have between the element and the current text. Just check your HTML with F12 and debug.